# React Native & Hermes: Is Additional Code Obfuscation Beneficial?

Tags: react-native, security, reverse-engineering, obfuscation, react-native-hermes

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently working with a RN project that involves compiling JavaScript into bytecode using Hermes. Given that Hermes inherently converts JS into bytecode, which is already challenging to reverse-engineer, I have a question regarding the additional use of a code obfuscator for the resulting bundle.js file.

Is there any practical benefit or added security in applying a code obfuscator to bundle.js in this context? My understanding is that the bytecode conversion by Hermes already provides a level of obfuscation.

Thank you for your time and assistance

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account existing solutions designed specifically to decompile Hermes bytcode, it's "obfuscation" is as good as non existent. It took me 5 minutes to decompile `index.android.bundle` into somewhat readable js, including the time to find a tool.

So  yes, if you're worried about source code security, additional js obfuscation is a must.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).